# CrudRepository MongoDB string id

Tags: java

error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

I try to find mongo document by id.
Old spring bot version allow me to search by:

```
public interface ConnRepository extendsCrudRepository<Conn, String> {
   @Override
   Conn findOne(String id);
```

I try to update spring boot to 2.1v nad get:

```
java:7: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
1 error
```

I know that CrudRepository change with new spring boot version, can you tell me how can I modify my code to search id by string ?

My repository class:

```
package com.spring.restapi.repositories;

import com.spring.restapi.models.Conn;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ConnRepository extends CrudRepository<Conn, String> {
@Override
Conn findOne(String id); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

findOne method has been replaced with `CrudRepository#findById`

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-944

Comment: Hi, I know, but how can I use it in my example ?